# How much time does it take for elasticsearch to delete a record?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In my program I am deleting one record from elasticsearch and then I am fetching the remaining records.

I have written 2 separate methods.
1 method to delete the record.
And another to fetch the remaining records.

But when I run the two methods It is returning all the records including the one i deleted.

I am running the program to fetch data only after getting success message from deleteRecords but it is giving all the records.

After few seconds If I run the program that I wrote to fetch remaining records alone  it is working fine It is returning the remaining methods alone.

When I tried running two methods in debug mode also it returned only the remaining records

Is there any way to solve this without using delay

Answer (score 3):

The index is refreshed every second by default, so that's why you don't see the result immediately. What you can do is to append [`?refresh=wait_for`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) to your delete call, in order to ensure that the next call will get the correct results you expect.

Note that adding this query string parameter will delay your call a little bit. In the worst case, it'll return after 1 second and it the best case, it'll return immediately depending on the time between two refreshes you made the call.

**Update ES 8.11**
I had a succession of `_delete_by_query` operations to perform in a loop. Only the first succeeded. The others failed silently but the `deleted` value in the response JSON was 0, meaning no LuceneDocuments had been deleted from the index (when many should have been, i.e. since they met the conditions in the request's DSL `data`).

Using "?refresh=wait_for" at the end of a URL ".../my_index/_delete_by_query" failed with the `reason` "Failed to parse value [wait_for] as only [true] or [false] are allowed.".

Using "?refresh=true" solved the problem.

The relevant page (for ES 8.11) is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html). This says that "wait_for" should work, as well as "true". Perhaps not for a `_delete_by_query` for some technical reason you (Val) might know... ?

Comment: Any other question, shall we close it?

Comment: @mikerodent let me investigate that and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java client, you are looking for threading of the API operation.

By default it is a separate thread which will execute the delete operation unless you explicitly ask it to do on the thread serving the request (which matches @Val's answer). This way the API call will block until the operation is finished.

```
DeleteResponse response = client.prepareDelete("documents", "doc", "1")
        .setOperationThreaded(false)   //look here!!!!
        .get();
```